# Помогите с ViewPager и FragmentManager Android

Tags: android

Вообщем в `Activity` у меня `TabLaoyt` и `ViewPage`

Естественно через `ViewPagerAdapter` создаются фрагменты.

У меня задача получить доступ к `view` элементам фрагмента, я так понял
это делается через `FragmentManager`

Но сделать этого я не могу так как создал фрагменты не через `FragmentManager`, а через `ViewPagerAdapter` так ведь?

Как быть?

Хочется и `TabLaoyt` и возможность обращаться к элементам и другие дела творить с фрагментом.

Comment: Не надо задавать одинаковые вопросы несколько раз. Свои вопросы можно править.